# Strange button in Status Strip Control in .NET

Tags: visual-studio-2019, statusstrip

I want to use a status strip in my program. I made it look and behave as I want, but I wanted to learn more.

I looked for some video tutorials, and I found something that I couldn't replicate in my program. In this video (https://youtu.be/gNlwCBtRULA?t=44), at second 45, the guy adds a button that he later uses to add components on the status bar:
[image: Additional button]

I am using Visual Studio 2019.
Can somebody please tell me what that button is and how to activate it on my end?
Thank you

Comment: You don't add that button yourself, it is the designer that does it.  Ready for you  to click and select an item to add to the bar.  Both the ToolStrip and StatusStrip designers do this.  If you don't see the button when you add either to a form then consider to pick a project template that supports them.  .NETFramework instead of .NETCore or .NET.  Or keep VS2019 updated, this designer feature was one of the last things they got working when porting Winforms to core.

Comment: @HansPassant, thank you for your answer. I have the latest version of VS: 16.9.1.  The application is WPF App (.NET Framework) Visual Basic.

Comment: Both the video and the screenshot are for Windows Forms, not WPF.  Google "wpf statusbar" to get ahead.

Comment: @HansPassant. Thank you for the information. I tested some projects using various combinations based on your answer, and I found that if I had selected .NET instead of .NET Framework, it would have been different. I Googled the difference between "Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)" and "Windows Forms App (.NET)", but all I found were references to differences to .NET Framework, Core, Standard, or WPF. I cannot find any comparison to blank .NET. Is it the same as Standard .NET?